# getting rid of MySQL SSL warning when using Java, JDBC and C3P0

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, c3p0

I have a simple JDBC app (not using Spring or Hibernate) that connects to MySQL. In production, the MySQL connection uses SSL, but it doesn't use SSL in development mode.  In development mode, I added `"&useSSL=false"` to the database URL in order to prevent the MySQL warning *"Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended"* from filling up my log files.

Now, I am adding a database connection pool using C3P0.  Instead of getting a connection from `DriverManager.getConnection`, I get the connection from C3P0 by calling `POOL.getConnection()`.

The code that sets up C3P0 is pretty simple:

```
POOL = new ComboPooledDataSource();
POOL.setDriverClass("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
POOL.setJdbcUrl(DB_URL);
POOL.setUser(USER);
POOL.setPassword(PASSWORD);
```

The problem is that this doesn't work. If the DB_URL string contains `"&useSSL=false"`, then `POOL.getConnection()` hangs. I've removed `"&useSSL=false"` from the `DB_URL`, and everything works ok, except that now I'm getting the MySQL SSL warnings.

Can anyone advise me on how to correctly configure C3P0 so that I no longer get the MySQL SSL warnings?

Comment: Are you using the same driver in the old situation? c3p0 also calls `DriverManager.getConnection`; so if one works the other should too. Consider posting your old code as well.

Comment: Mark -- The driver is the same ("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver") in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

JDBC Connections silently collect warnings that must be actively checked to be seen. Most applications never check them. c3p0 does. Whenever a Connection is checked back in, c3p0 checks, logs, and clears Connection warnings before making the Connection available again within the pool.

If the logging of warnings is annoying to you, just configure your logging library to filter them. All warnings are logged at INFO to a logger called `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.SQLWarnings`. Just configure whatever logging library you are using not to log `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.SQLWarnings, or to filter it to a higher level of severity than INFO.

See [SQLWarnings](https://github.com/swaldman/c3p0/blob/9f97c814aef31b2997d6ecfad1e3875c6136317b/src/java/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/SQLWarnings.java).

Comment: This doesn't entirely match up with the problem description that _"POOL.getConnection() hangs"_

Comment: That's only if the poster supplies Connection parameter `&useSSL=false`, which it looks like his DBMS is not supporting. If he uses SSL, i.e. if he omits `&useSSL=false`, then he succeeds at acquiring Connections, but receives a warning that the SSL Connection is to an unverifiable identity. Obviously the best thing to do would be to set up SSL with verifiable certificates, so there'd be a secure, verified identity. But if the poster is not worried about man-in-the-middle attacks and just wants the warnings to disappear, turning them off in logging will work.